# ```AttributeError``` when attempting to call a repo action

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, github-actions, pygithub

I am receiving an error message of `AttributeError` when attempting to call a repo and its actions.

This is my current code:

```
from github import Github

#Authenticate with GitHub
g = Github("<user>", "<pass>") #Replace <user>, <pass> with your user login and password



#Get the repository
repo = g.get_repo('toughjay318/los-lobos') #Replace 'owner/repo' with the name of your repository


# Determine which actions have permissions set on the repo
actions = repo.get_actions()

if not actions.permissions:
    print('No actions have permissions set on the repo')
else:
    for action in actions.permissions:
        print(f'{action} has permissions set on the repo')

# Determine if pipelines are configured for commits
pipelines = repo.get_workflows()
if not pipelines.totalCount:
    print('No pipelines are configured for commits')
else:
    print(f'{pipelines.totalCount} pipelines are configured for commits')

# Determine if new branches are configured for actions on commits
branch_protection = repo.get_branch_protection('main') #Replace 'main' with the name of your default branch
if not branch_protection.restrictions:
    print('New branches are not configured for actions on commits')
else:
    print('New branches are configured for actions on commits')
```

This is the full errror message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [20], in <cell line: 12>()
      8 repo = g.get_repo('toughjay318/los-lobos') #Replace 'owner/repo' with the name of your repository
     11 # Determine which actions have permissions set on the repo
---> 12 actions = repo.get_actions()
     14 if not actions.permissions:
     15     print('No actions have permissions set on the repo')

AttributeError: 'Repository' object has no attribute 'get_actions'
```

I have tried changing the commands around and I cannot figure out why this error is happening. Could anyone please assist me in anyway possible?

Comment: There's literally no method called `get_actions` -- what makes you think this should work? See all [valid methods here](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html).

Comment: Yeah, that method seems to not exist.  Did you copy it from some example somewhere, or did you just make it up?

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated by [issue 1373](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/1373), support for GitHub Actions in PyGithub is requested as far back as Jan. 2020.

You could try and integrate [PR 1734](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/pull/1734) ("Support for artifacts API") and modify it to query permissions on actions.